# How to get seed from grbtune and set it in Gurobi?

Tags: gurobi

I have tuned my model with `grbtune` and depending on the seed used, the runtime changes a lot: For example:

```
Testing candidate parameter set 11 ...

    Method 0
    MIPFocus 1
    Cuts 2

Solving with random seed #1 ... runtime 1.85s
Solving with random seed #2 ... runtime 10.77s
Solving with random seed #3 ... runtime 10.51s

Improvement found:
  baseline: mean runtime 14.85s
  improved: mean runtime 7.71s
```

How can I retrieve random seed #1 in this example and how can I set this seed (as far as I know, this should be possible, but the gurobi docs do not mention setting the seed)?

Comment: There is a [Seed](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/seed.html) parameter that you can use to modify the seed number.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that. Still I need to know how to access the seed from grbtune.

Comment: Keep in mind that a seed that produces a quick solution on one instance of a model will not necessarily produce a quick solution on another instance of the same model (with different parameter values).